# Google Play Services Unity Plugin Show Leaderboard

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am building a game for Android and iOS with Unity, and I have imported this: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

I have created the game at the Google play Console, and I see my leaderboard. No data is uploaded however - even tho I have ran my code several times - first time was about 4 days ago. But still, no data is there.

I am able to log in successfully.

I am nor able to show the Leaderboard, which I would like to.

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect (Screen.width/2 - 105*u, Screen.height/3 + 450*u, 210*u, 210*u), "Score")){
                // Activate the Google Play Games platform
                PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
                PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
                Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {});
                Social.ReportScore(PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("best"), "CxxxxQ", (bool s) => {});
                ((PlayGamesPlatform) Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI("CxxxxQ");
}
```

Comment: did you check bool callback from ReportScore method. You may not be able to report score properly. Is your test account is added in Google play Console

Comment: Did everything you just said. It turns out it's conflicting with an other plugin.

Comment: Me too. Hope it's not on the onGUI issues. It might only show on the activity start or update but I haven't test it yet.

Comment: Which plugin was conflicting and how?

Comment: @user2947684 which plugin was it conflicting with??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using google.service.game;
GoogleGame.Instance().login (true, false);
GoogleGame.Instance().showLeaderboards();
```

[download code](https://github.com/unity-plugins/google-play-game-service-unity-plugin)